# Branch display showing (master-> origin) rather than just (master)

Tags: git, cmder

What is the difference in notation?

On my one workstation the git repo I cloned shows (master) and the other it shows (master -> origin)

I've also created a new local repository, committed a text file and the prompt still shows:
 *path*(master -> origin)

doing a git branch reveals that the only branch is master.

I searched for documentation on why this would be but I don't understand why one is different from the other.

Comment: The first does not have a tracking branch, the second does?

Answer (score 4):

Do a `git branch -avv`

You should see the local master branch has an upstream branch origin/master associated to it.
That would explain the `(master -> origin)` notation.
See more in "[Remote branches](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches)"

The OP mentions using Cmder.

Looking at [`github.com/cmderdev/cmder`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder), I can see it is [using  `git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/blob/d9fcf06e0fc29910d09a47abc8d864c11156b7c4/vendor/git-prompt.sh), which in turn is caling [`git/git/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh).
A `git config -l` might show a difference between the repo.
The value of `GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM` can also be relevant.

Comment: @Matt_G init repo or cloned repo? An init repo has no branch until you make the first commit.

Comment: The question concerned a cloned repo, but I created a local test repo to see if it came out differently. It did not, and after the first commit the only branch was "master" but the branch notation still showed (master -> origin)

Comment: @Matt_G Can you edit your question with the exact command you are typing, and the exact output showing a `master -> origin`?

Comment: I have edited the question and hope that makes it more clear. But the branch notation on the prompt path is showing (master -> origin)

Comment: @Matt_G Right... the prompt! On Cmder, so Windows I suppose? Is it in a git bash?

Comment: @Matt_G Then my answer stands: the prompt reflects the upstream branch (the one you can see with a `git branch -vv`)

Comment: The prompt is in cmdr. [here is a screenshot of the issue](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/1659). Doing agit branch -vv only shows "*master"

Comment: I have done some testing and it appears to be a version issue with either git or cmder. I have copied the older version and am using that right now which displays the branch similarly to the other repository.

Comment: @Matt_G Sorry, the older version of what?

Comment: Sorry - cmder that was bundled with git. The version that appears to function properly is 1.3.2 bundled with git "2.11.0.windows.1", and the newest version has notation changes looks to be 1.3.5 bundled with git "2.16.1.windows.4". Due to the unexpected change in notation and the inability to find documentation describing the change, I'm holding off on using the newer version.

Comment: @Matt_G PL/ 2.16.2 would be ideal ;)

Answer (score 1):

As of version 1.3.18 you can modify the `git_prompt_filter` function located in
`cmder\vendor\clink-completions\git_prompt.lua`

This is the code displaying the prompt

```lua
local text = remote_to_push
if (remote_ref) then text = text..'/'..remote_ref end

if (text == '') then
    clink.prompt.value = clink.prompt.value:gsub(escape('('..branch), '%1'..text)
else
    clink.prompt.value = clink.prompt.value:gsub(escape('('..branch), '%1 -> '..text)
end
```

You can change it to

```lua
local text = remote_to_push
if (remote_ref) then text = text..'/'..remote_ref end

clink.prompt.value = clink.prompt.value:gsub(escape('('..branch), '%1'.."")
```